# How do I keep step counting fragment in the background?

Tags: android, android-fragments, background-process

I have a step counting app, the app is removed from memory after a certain time and the step count is reset which is something I don't want. How do I keep the app running in the background so that I can get the correct number of steps taken. Do I use Bound Services?

```
package com.example.nina.stepcounter3;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements SensorEventListener {

SensorManager sensorManager;
TextView tv_steps;
boolean running = false;
Button btn;
View myView;

int initialValue;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_layout, container, false);

    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_layout, container, false);
    tv_steps = (TextView) rl.findViewById(R.id.tv_steps);
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);



    return rl;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    running = true;
    Sensor countSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
    if (countSensor != null) {
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, countSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    } else {
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    running = false;
    // unregister
    //sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}
static int initialStepCount = 0;
static int stepCount = 0;
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (initialStepCount == 0) {
        initialStepCount = (int) event.values[0];
    }

    stepCount = (int)event.values[0] - initialStepCount;

    if (running) {
        tv_steps.setText(String.valueOf(stepCount));

    }
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}
}
```

Comment: you should count steps in service, and show the numbers in Activity (or fragment)

Comment: That means I have to create a new class that extends service @VladMatvienko?

Comment: yes, and move step counting logic into it. Also possibly make it not a simple service, but a foreground service to ensure it will continue running regardless of your Activity's lifecycle.

Comment: How do send the data from the service to the fragment? do I user intents or broadcast receivers @VladMatvienko?

Comment: how about searching? You can use intents, binding, broadcast receiver, singletone, or one of a hundred of other ways.

Comment: I'm doing that :D  I meant what's the best way? @VladMatvienko but do I use a started service or a bound service? I read that bound services get terminated with the client while started services can run indefinitely?

Comment: yes, the started one, and it should be a foreground service I believe (to prevent it being killed over time). As for me, best way is to use a library like EventBus. It makes it easier to communicate between classes, if you shouldn't pass an instance of one class into another (link to Activity into the service)